# can i use hashtable to store a combination of string and an integer

Tags: vb.net

If I have a file such as follows:

```
C
D
E
A
A
B
```

I want to store the repeats of all the strings

```
A 2
B 1
C 1
D 1
E 1
```

I started with Arrays by defining custom class but I found it painful to delete an item in that array. I read that Hashtables is very flexible to add/delete items

```
Dim File1Reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(TextBox1.Text)
Dim lineCount1 = File.ReadAllLines(TextBox1.Text).Length

Dim File1line As String
Dim file1items(lineCount1) As String
Do While File1Reader.Peek() <> -1
    File1line = File1Reader.ReadLine
    If File1line.Length > 0 Then
        file1items(i) = File1line
    End If

    i = i + 1
Loop

System.Array.Sort(Of String)(file1items)

Dim file1table As New Hashtable()
Dim file1count As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()

For x = 0 To (lineCount1 - 2)

    If file1items(x) = file1items(x + 1) Then
        c = c + 1
    Else
        c = 1
    End If

    file1count.Add(file1items(x), c)
Next

    MsgBox(file1count(0))
```

I get the following error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Value cannot be null.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: You're not using your `HashTable` anywhere in the program. A `Dictionary<Of String, Integer>` on its own should be sufficient to store unique letters and their counts for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely doing this the hard way.

```
Dim results As List(Of IGrouping(Of String, String)) =
         File.ReadLines(TextBox1.Text).
              GroupBy(Function(s) s.Trim()).
              OrderBy(Function(g) g.Key). 
              ToList()

MsgBox(String.Format("{0,-5}{1}",results(0).Key, results(0).Count()))
```

It's not clear from the question how you want things sorted. If you care more about the count than the key, you may want to use the below code instead. Note the addition of the `Select()` linq operator, which improves performance in this case by avoiding the need to keep re-counting the groups. Also, I had to fall back to type inference for the `results` variable because of the anonymous type.

```
Dim results = File.ReadLines(TextBox1.Text).
              GroupBy(Function(s) s.Trim()).
              Select(Function(g) New With {.Key = g.Key, .Count = g.Count()}).
              OrderBy(Function(g) g.Count * -1).
              ThenBy(Function(g) g.Key).
              ToList()

MsgBox(String.Format("{0,-5}{1}",results(0).Key, results(0).Count))
```

Comment: VB.Net... not your father's VB6.